# Verify that config value applied in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

WSL configuation can be set in `wsl.conf`(for distro) or .`wslconfig` (global),  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config). Is there a way to verify that a value has been applied?

Something like `echo $propName` in bash/zsh?

Comment: Apologies - Should have voted to migrate this to Super User instead of closing, but check the [WSL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-subsystem-for-linux/info) for details -- Would you repost on Super User?  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds look at questions under the WSL tags. Questions are similar, about the environment itself, and not about coding.